How to set up Typescript for LWC?
Since Salesforce introduced typescript support as a developer preview, I am trying to create an LWC component with .ts file, I followed all the steps mentioned in the below salesforce documentation.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/ts.html#add-the-typescript-package-to-your-lwc-project
I am not able to understand the very first point to enable the typescript in the sfdx project below is the screenshot for the same.

I don't see any settings.json file anywhere in the project so I created one but that didn't solve the problem(it did not automatically created tsconfig.json file under the LWC folder. I manully created it). After reading this documentation 100 times, I followed all the instructions carefully but still I am keep getting below error from the tsconfig.json file

Cannot read file 'c:/Users/mypc/Documents/Salesforce
project/TypeScriptProject/.sfdx/tsconfig.sfdx.json'

I created one regular LWC named helloTypeScript and replaces helloTypeScript.js with helloTypeScript.ts but when I try to deploy it is keep failing because it still expecting .js file

force-app\main\default\lwc\helloTypeScript\helloTypeScript.js-meta.xml
No base file for markup://c:helloTypeScript

I have below tsconfig.json file under force-app\main\default\lwc folder
{
    // These sections are automatically generated
  
    "extends": "../../../../.sfdx/tsconfig.sfdx.json",
    "include": [
      "**/*.ts",
      "../../../../.sfdx/typings/lwc**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/__tests__/**"
    ],
  
    // You have to manually add the compilerOptions section
  
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": false
    }
  }


A few things:

Create setting.json in your root folder. This should result in a tsconfig.json file being created in your lwc folder (see below for a screenshot). You may need to restart VS Code for this to work.
(This step isn't documented) Add "type": "module" to your package.json file.  See below for screenshot.

You're then ready to create a ts hello world file.
My hello world file:
ts file
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

interface myInterface {
    hello: string
}

export default class TsHellowWorld extends LightningElement {
    message: myInterface = { hello: 'world' }
}

html file
<template>
    Hello {message.hello}!
</template>

You then convert to js by running npx tsc --project ./force-app/main/default/lwc (update if you use a different path)
This creates the relevant js file that you can deploy to your org.
e.g
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class TsHellowWorld extends LightningElement {
    message = { hello: 'world' };
}

Screenshots for context



I did exactly as mentioned in your answer, but it is still not working, I am still getting an error

@gs650x which error when doing what?

Also, what version of the cli are you using?

I am gettting No source-backed components present in the package and I am on 2.61.8

@gs650x That sounds like a different error. Did this solve the original problems with setting up a typescript project?  If so, mark this as the correct answer, then look into your next problem.  It might be solved by:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360441/trailhead-dreamhouse-error-running-forcesourcedeploy-no-source-backed-compon
